Errors while trying to install matplotlib
I am not python expert and this project used to work but now giving me massive red errors while trying to build the project:
pip2 install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
Can somebody help me to figure out how to fix it. It seems the issue related to matplotlib and numpy as far as I could tell.
I am using macOS Sonoma 14.4.1 (23E224).
python version: Python 2.7.18
and pip version: pip 20.3.4.
this is my requirement file:
astropy == 2.0.16
atomicwrites == 1.4.0
attrs == 21.2.0
backports.functools-lru-cache == 1.6.4
bidict == 0.18.4
colorama == 0.4.4
cycler == 0.10.0
funcsigs == 1.0.2
kiwisolver == 1.1.0
matplotlib == 2.2.5
mock == 1.3.0
more-itertools == 5.0.0
nose == 1.3.7
numpy == 1.16.6
pandas == 0.24.2
pbr == 1.3.0
pluggy == 0.7.1
py == 1.11.0
pyparsing == 2.4.7
python-dateutil == 2.8.2
pytz == 2021.3
scipy == 1.2.3
six == 1.16.0
tk == 0.1.0
tqdm == 4.62.3
wheel == 0.24.0
lmfit == 0.9.15

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/duaa.jaber/personalWorkSpace/asad/asad_dev_0.1.0/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/t_/b3qw1kjj7sx5gxc_10fdxnbr0000gq/T/pip-install-kadPSo/matplotlib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/t_/b3qw1kjj7sx5gxc_10fdxnbr0000gq/T/pip-install-kadPSo/matplotlib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/t_/b3qw1kjj7sx5gxc_10fdxnbr0000gq/T/pip-pip-egg-info-EdE3Nz
         cwd: /private/var/folders/t_/b3qw1kjj7sx5gxc_10fdxnbr0000gq/T/pip-install-kadPSo/matplotlib/
    Complete output (3002 lines):
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options
    
    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: yes [2.2.5]
                    python: yes [2.7.18 (default, May 18 2024, 18:29:57)  [GCC
                            Apple LLVM 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)]]
                  platform: yes [darwin]
    
    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                     numpy: yes [not found. pip may install it below.]
          install_requires: yes [handled by setuptools]
                    libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]
                  freetype: yes [version 2.13.2]
                       png: yes [version 1.6.43]
                     qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'libqhull' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]
    
    OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
               sample_data: yes [installing]
                  toolkits: yes [installing]
                     tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
            toolkits_tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
    
    OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                    macosx: yes [installing, darwin]
                    qt5agg: no  [PySide2 not found; PyQt5 not found]
                    qt4agg: no  [PySide not found; PyQt4 not found]
                   gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
    DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /Users/duaa.jaber/personalWorkSpace/asad/asad_dev_0.1.0/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/t_/b3qw1kjj7sx5gxc_10fdxnbr0000gq/T/pip-wheel-3XAIjW/numpy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/t_/b3qw1kjj7sx5gxc_10fdxnbr0000gq/T/pip-wheel-3XAIjW/numpy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/t_/b3qw1kjj7sx5gxc_10fdxnbr0000gq/T/pip-wheel-lhR0EK
           cwd: /private/var/folders/t_/b3qw1kjj7sx5gxc_10fdxnbr0000gq/T/pip-wheel-3XAIjW/numpy/
      Complete output (2908 lines):
      Running from numpy source directory.
      blas_opt_info:
      blas_mkl_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Users/duaa.jaber/personalWorkSpace/asad/asad_dev_0.1.0/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
    
      blis_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries blis not found in ['/Users/duaa.jaber/personalWorkSpace/asad/asad_dev_0.1.0/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
    
      openblas_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries openblas not found in ['/Users/duaa.jaber/personalWorkSpace/asad/asad_dev_0.1.0/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
    
      atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries tatlas not found in ['/Users/duaa.jaber/personalWorkSpace/asad/asad_dev_0.1.0/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
    
      atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries satlas not found in ['/Users/duaa.jaber/personalWorkSpace/asad/asad_dev_0.1.0/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
    
      atlas_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/Users/duaa.jaber/personalWorkSpace/asad/asad_dev_0.1.0/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
    
      atlas_blas_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/Users/duaa.jaber/personalWorkSpace/asad/asad_dev_0.1.0/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
    
      accelerate_info:
        FOUND:
          extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
          define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
          extra_compile_args = ['-faltivec', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
    
        FOUND:
          extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
          define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
          extra_compile_args = ['-faltivec', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
    
      /bin/sh: svnversion: command not found
      non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
      lapack_opt_info:
      lapack_mkl_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Users/duaa.jaber/personalWorkSpace/asad/asad_dev_0.1.0/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
    
      openblas_lapack_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries openblas not found in ['/Users/duaa.jaber/personalWorkSpace/asad/asad_dev_0.1.0/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
    
      openblas_clapack_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/Users/duaa.jaber/personalWorkSpace/asad/asad_dev_0.1.0/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE
    

I can't post the whole error body as it is 3000+ lines.

Note that you are using Python 2.7 which has reached its end of life more than 4 years ago

yes unfortunately i need to use this version.

I think your problem is that your operating system is too new so there are no compatible wheels (i.e. pre-compiled packages).  This means pip will try to compile Matplotlib from source, which requires a whole bunch of dependencies.  Trying to get all that straight for such an old package is going to be painful.  I just tried your requirements file in a python2.7 environment under Ubuntu 22.04 and it successfully installed the manylinux wheels.  So if you really need this old project the easiest thing might be to find a cheap laptop and install linux on it.

I'd recommend running these codes in step to see if it fixes the issue. How important is this project? Why are you unable to upgrade to a newer python?
1- Update pip and setuptools
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools

2- Use compatible versions of numpy and matplotlib that are compatible with your python (you may need to update the matplotlib version in your requirements.txt):
matplotlib==2.2.5

3- Install dependencies for numpy and matplotlib
pip install numpy==1.16.6
pip install matplotlib==2.2.5

4- MAY NOT BE NECESSARY But modifying your build environment, can avoid possible compilation issues:
pip install numpy==1.16.6 --no-build-isolation
pip install matplotlib==2.2.5 --no-build-isolation

